# Interop: Retrieving the COM class factory

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

I was developing a 32-bit application in VS2013 using a 32-bit Win 7.
I used a registered COM named 'xpdfText.dll', registered in %windir%\system32, as expected.
The code was as follows:

```
    public static string PDF_XPDF(byte[] PDFByte = null, string filename = null, string mode = "layout")
    {

        XpdfText.XpdfText pdf;
        pdf = new XpdfText.XpdfText();


        if (filename == null)
        {
            // Create a UCOMIStream from the allocated memory
            IStream comStream;
            Common.CreateStreamOnHGlobal(IntPtr.Zero, true, out comStream);
            comStream.Write(PDFByte, PDFByte.Length, IntPtr.Zero);
            pdf.loadStream(comStream);
        }
        else
            pdf.loadFile(filename);

        if (mode == "layout")
            pdf.physicalLayoutMode = true;

        pdf.textEncoding = "Latin1";
        int n = pdf.numPages;
        string lines = pdf.convertToTextString(1, n);

        return lines;
    }
```

Recently, I bought a new computer and moved to a 64 bit Win 7.
As my solution is to be deployed in 32 bit systems, I chose the target platform for my C# project to be x86 (instead of "Any CPU", by default) and thus I also chose to register the same 32-bit xpdftext.dll in %windir%\syswow64.

When I debug the program, everything goes well until the line when the class 'pdf' is initiliazed:

pdf = new XpdfText.XpdfText();

It shows up the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Needless to say, CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} does not exist, so I don't understand what I've done wrong.
I have read a lot of threads and followed the guidelines but, to this time, no idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that component didn't travel that well to your new machine.  How that ended up producing that bogus CLSID {guid} is however extremely hard to explain.  That number comes from the type library and was generated when you added a reference to your project.  I suspect you've been hacking around another problem and didn't tell us.  Only reasonable thing you can do is remove the reference and add it back, might work.  The company that owns it has a support phone number, looks like you are going to have to call it.

Comment: I already emailed the company, though at the same time posted the question here, because I am not sure if the problem is due to the DLL, but to a deeper trouble. On the other hand, it would be dumber on my part to hide something if I wanted my problem to be solved, nor do I have the required skills to hack anything.

Comment: Something weird is happening. I created another project an it works, but in the first one not...

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I managed to solve the problem.
It was as simple as modifying a flag in the properties of the COM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed target platform to 32xbit instead of 64xbit or Any CPU

*Project>> Properties>>Build>>Target Platform*